# acro translations.sty not found

Tags: classicthesis, acro

I am new to latex, but am using it to write my thesis.

I was hoping to add a list of abbreviations and nomenclature with the `acro` package.

In the main document I have:

```
\usepackage{acro}

\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]

\printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name=Nomenclature]
```

however I get an error message saying:

```
translations.sty not found.
```

And help would be great.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You have either an outdated or an incomplete installation of your TeX distribution...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because updating/completing the TeX distribution will solve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)